# Show two columns instead of two rows in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the query shown here, and it shows two rows due to project_type is selection (Internal, Project) column.

My requirement is to show `sum(unit.amount)` two columns for `project_type` - instead of two rows.

```sql
SELECT project_id, project_type, SUM(unit_amount)
FROM account_analytic_line
WHERE project_id = 2
GROUP BY project_type, project_id
```

Current result:

```
469;"Internal";154.416666666667
469;"Project";3963.08333333333
```

Required result:

```
469; 154.416666666667; 3963.08333333333
```

Comment: `SELECT project_id, SUM(unit_amount) FILTER (WHERE project_type = 'Internal'), SUM(unit_amount) FILTER (WHERE project_type = 'Project')  FROM account_analytic_line where project_id = 2 GROUP BY project_id`

Comment: Thanks @Felix its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting 2 rows because you use `project_type` in the `GROUP BY` clause.
You must group by `project_id` only and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT project_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN project_type = 'Internal' THEN unit_amount ELSE 0 END) sum_Internal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN project_type = 'Project' THEN unit_amount ELSE 0 END) sum_Project
FROM account_analytic_line
WHERE project_id = 2
GROUP BY project_id
```